# image preprocessing error in tensorflow

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have input function that reads all lines from the filename argument. Then it applies parser function to each line. Every line in my .csv file is as following: "path_to_img, label_num". Here is the code:

```
def input_fn(filename):

    def parser(column):
        d = tf.decode_csv(column, record_defaults=[[''], [-1]])
        img, label = d
        img = tf.read_file(img)
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
        img = tf.image.resize_images(img, (300, 200))
        img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
        return {'image': img}, label

    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename).map(parser)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(None).shuffle(5000).batch(500)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Then I create classifier and train:

```
feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image', shape=(300, 200))]

model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier([4028, 1024, 512], feature_columns=feat_cols, model_dir=OUTDIR, n_classes=5)

model.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn('data.csv'), steps=1000)
```

But eventually I'm getting an error relate to decode operation and still can't understand what's wrong

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\"\"\"\n    flickr.p'
 [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false](ReadFile)]]
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,300,200,1], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

Comment: It seems like the filenames in your CSV files aren't formatted / escaped properly. Could you share some CSV line examples to check?

Comment: @Aldream, yes. a line looks like "flowers/daisy/image.jpg, 0". I use relative path

Comment: It may actually be that one of your files listed in the CSV isn't an image / isn't properly encoded, hence `tf.read_file()` returning a string (starting with "`\"\"\"\n    flickr.p`" cf. your trace) which can't be decoded as an image.